# Multilanguage profiles in StackExchange Careers

Tags: support, jobs, profile-page, languages, localization

I'm currently updating my StackExchange Careers profile with some updated information. But in fact, I have the option to change the language in the bottom part of the page, but it will just change the Display language of the page not the way I can edit my profile.

This means I just can generate a single language profile which is displayed in german on the german page and in german on the english page. Or the otherway round, english in english and english in german.

Is there any way to generate a *real* multilanguage profile?